# How to augment the classpath used by SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

To be clear, my problem is not that my tests cannot find the application context.  My problem is that other files that are searched for on the classpath cannot be found.  My pom.xml runs the tests with additional classpath entries, so the build works fine, but it's annoying that if I want to run the tests manually in Eclipse, I have to edit the run configuration to add a particular subdirectory of the project to the classpath.  I'd really like to figure out how to specify this in the test class itself. The "@ContextConfiguration" annotation comes close to this, but that's just for loading the application context.

How can I specify in an annotation in the test class itself that a particular subdirectory of the project needs to be added to the classpath when the test runs?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I specify in an annotation in the test class itself that a particular subdirectory of the project needs to be added to the classpath when the test runs?

That's unfortunately not possible.

You'll need to ensure that you can properly import your Maven project into Eclipse -- for example, with the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

Comment: It's already imported into Eclipse. I should have mentioned that. I'm not aware of any augmentation of run configurations that looks at the surefire or failsafe configuration of the POM.

Comment: I've filed a Spring enhancement request to provide something like this.  It's at least been promoted to triage, so it wasn't immediately rejected.

Comment: Yeah, I know... it's assigned to me and awaiting my triaging efforts. ;-)